# C++ or v8 for game engine

Tags: javascript, c++, directx, game-engine, v8

I have built a few games using various engines in js/html5 and even in c++ using irrlicht (tried ogre, but i prefer irrlicht's simplicity).

The next step I want to take is building a game engine, and since i have experience with c++ and have used v8, I have been thinking of making a windows only game engine that use's v8 to wrap directx for graphics and bullet for physics (haven't decided the rest), and then calls a js file/string that has the bulk of my game engine which call's these c++ api's, and then the user can build their game entirely using js.

**The question** though is, if I were to make a commercial game that competes with other AAA titles on the pc, should I really use a v8/js powered game engine or should I just do everything in c++?

**Why am I asking this?**
1) All the C++ api's that I will be using will be wrapped by v8 for use in js.
2) v8/js win over C++ pointers and manual memory management (garbage collection)

If it weren't for point 2, I'd use c++, but right now I'd prefer using js, but that leads to my question as I one day want to make a real game (maybe not a AAA title, but that's the performance and quality that I want), and would prefer to make one game engine only, rather then making a new one (or picking a new one) for each new project/game, but if I consider point 1, that's allot of C++ api's that I will be wrapping, so I'm wondering if I will have performance issues?

Comment: "Not a constructive question". Better written than most, though. It all really depends upon the target desired. Even if V8 is fast, it is still a good order of magnitude or two "slower" than C++. Also, in games the manual memory allocation is a *good* thing; it is often better to amortize than suffer the occasional GC "hiccup". Of course, your target(s) might never have these as factors to consider: in which case development time reduction might be highly favorable for V8.

Comment: Well written C++ shouldn't _have_ manual memory management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ has been used in development of several game engines because of its high performance. So if you want to make a game that is more efficient and fast (it also depends on how you code, efficient code definitly makes the difference). Yes C++ lack garbage collection but the performance it offer is definitly worth to manually handle memory managment. If your preferences are making a efficient game engine and if you have time, you should go with C++.

Comment: well sed. :) ...

Comment: @arcyqwerty .. almost spit out my coffee ^^

Comment: thx, looks like I'll be taking the C++ route

Comment: Manual memory management? Modern C++ does not need manual memory management. We have RAII.

Comment: but he didn't mention that which standerd he is going to use, so thats why I answered for C++ 99 standered.

Comment: @UmerFarooq There is no C++99. It's either C++98, C++03 or C++11.

Comment: "C++98, C++03 or C++11"?
I always thought there was only C++ and C++11 only lol

Answer (score 1):

I'm experienced with mmo games and I can for sure say

C++ is better for server multiplayer online games, because of packet encryption methods, SQL querying speed, the speed of the application itself, the multithreading possibilities, handling millions of functions at a time. (ex: 500 players online, 500 player send a packet to move to another position, a function called CPacketHandle::OnPlayerMove( CPacket* pPacket, D3DXVECTOR3 *pPos.... ) would be called 500 times by packet).

You can manually manage everything in c++, if something is automatic you may encounter situations you cannot handle something the exactly way you want to, sometime misleading hours of previous coding.
In my opinion i'd use C++ over anyother language for pratically anything else